# Enviar cálculo de JavaScript a PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, post

Muchas gracias a todos. Mil gracias a @iNavac, gracias a toda su ayuda y a la del resto del colectivo he conseguido mandar con exito la información recogida con ajax usando el siguiente codigo:

```html
 foreach ($_POST['values'] as $key => $value) { 
 
   $value['idItem'];
   $value['quantity'];
   $value['subTotal'];
  
 $email_message .= " prueba nombre ".clean_string($value['idItem'])."\n";
 $email_message .= "prueba cantidad: ".clean_string($value['quantity'])."\n";   
 $email_message .= "prueba subtotal: ".clean_string($value['subTotal'])."\n";
    }
 




   $email_message .= "total: ".clean_string($total)."\n";
```

Aqui expongo los datos que me muestra Developer tool de Chrome. Lo cual demuestra que el envio de la información al php através de ajax esta funcionando bien. El problema es que no consigo llamar a esa información desde mi php para mandarla por correo

> values[0][idItem]:quantity_item_1 values[0][quantity]:9
>   values[0][subTotal]:9 values[1][idItem]:quantity_item_2
>   values[1][quantity]:10 values[1][subTotal]:20
>   values[2][idItem]:quantity_item_3 values[2][quantity]:0
>   values[2][subTotal]:0 values[3][idItem]:quantity_item_4
>   values[3][quantity]:0 values[3][subTotal]:0 total:29
>   email:joe@example.com

Otra de las variaciones que he probado es

```
foreach ($_POST['values'] as $key => $quantity){
$email_message .= " items: ".clean_string($values)."\n";
}
```

En este caso. Desaparece la palabra Array pero no me indica ninguna cantidad.

Sigo trabajando en solucionar el problema de recoger las variables foreach en mi correo de confirmación.
De momento solo consigo que aparezca la palabra Array.
Actualizo documento php con el codigo que estoy usando.
Gracias

El codigo que iNavac ha proporcionado es perfecto. Si alguien me puede ayudar a formular el PHP para poder mandar las variables quantity y subtotal de los diferentes items estaría muy agradecido. El precio total y email llegan perfectos. Muchas gracias a todos. A base de cabezazos empeño, y sobre todo vuestra ayuda aprendo poco a poco.

```html
<?php



if(isset($_POST['email'])) {



    $email_to = "example@lcontact.com";

    $email_subject = "order";   

    $email_from = $_POST['email'];
 

    $$quantity_item_3 = $_POST['$quantity_item_3']; // 

  
    $total = $_POST['total']; // requerido 
    
 foreach ($_POST['values'] as $key => $quantity) {
 $email_message .= " item prueba 4: ".clean_string($quantity)."\n";

}


    $error_message = "Error";





    //A partir de aqui se contruye el cuerpo del mensaje tal y como llegará al correo

    $email_message = "Contenido del Mensaje.\n\n";
 
     
 
    function clean_string($string) {
 
      $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
 
      return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
 
    }


 
    $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";
 



   $email_message .= " item prueba 3: ".clean_string($quantity_item_3)."\n";



   $email_message .= "total: ".clean_string($total)."\n";
   




//Se crean los encabezados del correo
 
$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
 
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
 
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
 
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  
 

?>
```

Tengo formulario en página html el cual procesa unos cálculos con javascript.

Para enviar el formulario uso un documento php.

Cuando recibo el email tengo los valores de cantidad pero no hay forma de conseguir el resultado de los cálculos para los subtotates y finaltotal.

He probado con input hidden, cambiando POST por GET, he probado a meterle ajax pero no lo consigo.

```js
    window.onerror = function(msg, url, linenumber) {
       
        return true;
    };


    function doTotals() {
        var productos = ['item1_', 'item2_', 'item3_', 'item4_'];
        var priceStr = 'price';
        var quantityStr = 'quantity';
        var subtotalStr = 'subtotal';


        var total = 0;

        for (var i = 0; i < productos.length; i++) {
         var price = document.getElementById(productos[i] + priceStr).value;
      var quantity = document.getElementById(productos[i] + quantityStr).value;
            document.getElementById(productos[i] + subtotalStr).innerHTML = ((price) * (quantity)).toFixed(4);
            total += price * quantity;    


        }
    output = document.getElementById("finaltotal");
    output.innerHTML = total.toFixed(4);

    }


    function setup() {
        var lastCol = document.getElementById("subtotal_header");
     
        var theForm = document.getElementById("contact-form");

        var amounts = document.getElementsByTagName("select");
        for(var i = 0; i < amounts.length; i++){
            amounts[i].onchange = doTotals;
        }


    }

    window.onload = setup;
```

```html
    <form id="contact-form" action="php/order.php">
                                    

    <table width="246%">
    <tr>
    <td width="25%" class="button-ps">Producto</td>
    <td width="11%" class="button-ps"> Precio Unidad</td>
    <td width="51%" class="button-ps">Selección</td>
    <td width="13%" class="button-ps">Subtotal</td>
    <tr>
    <td><label for="spray_quantity" class="black"><b>Limpiador gafas en Spray</b></label></td>

    <td><span class="black">1</span>  <input type="hidden" id="item1_price" value="1"></td>
    <td><select id="item1_quantity" name="item1_quantity" size="1">
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="0" selected>0</option>
    </select>
    </td>
    <td class="black" id="item1_subtotal"></td>
    <tr>
    <td><label for="item2_quantity" class="black"><b>item2</b></label></td>

    <td class="black">2<input type="hidden" id="item2_price" value="2"></td>
    <td><select id="item2_quantity" name="item2_quantity" size="1">
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="0" selected>0</option>
    </select>
    </td>
    <td class="black" id="item2_subtotal"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td><label for="item3_quantity" class="black"><b>item3</b></label></td>

    <td><span class="black">3€</span>  <input type="hidden" id="item3_price" value="3"></td>
    <td><select id="item3_quantity" name="item3_quantity" size="1"><br/ >
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="0" selected>0</option>
    </select>
    </td>
    <td class="black" id="item3_subtotal" name= "item3_subtotal"></td>
                                      
    <tr>
    <td><label for="item4_quantity" class="black"><b>item4</b></label></td>

    <td><span class="black">4</span>  <input type="hidden" id="item4_price" value="4"></td>
    <td><select id="item4_quantity" name="item4_quantity" size="1">
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="0" selected>0</option>
    </select>
    </td>
    <td class="black" id="item4_subtotal" name="item4_subtotal"></td>
    </tr>
                  
                                        
    <tr id="tablefoot"><td class="button-ps">Total:</td><td colspan="2" class="button-ps" id="totalerr"><td class="label-success" id="finaltotal" name="finaltotal"></td></tr>

    </table>
    <button id="send-mail" class="message-btn">send</button>
    </form>
```

PHP

```
order.php


<?php



if(isset($_POST['email'])) {



    $email_to = "example@contact.com";

    $email_subject = "order";   




    $spray_quantity = $_POST['item1_quantity']; // 

    $spray_subtotal = $_POST['item1_subtotal']; // 

    $esponja_quantity = $_POST['item2_quantity']; //

    $esponja_subtotal = $_POST['item2_subtotal']; // 

    $kit_quantity = $_POST['item3_quantity']; // 

    $kit_subtotal = $_POST['item3_subtotal']; // 

    $gamuza14x14_quantity = $_POST['item4_quantity']; // requerido

    $gamuza14x14_subtotal = $_POST['item4_subtotal']; // requerido

    $finaltotal = $_POST['finaltotal']; // requerido

    $error_message = "Error";





    $email_message = "Contenido del Mensaje.\n\n";



    function clean_string($string) {

      $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");

      return str_replace($bad,"",$string);

    }







   $email_message .= " item1: ".clean_string($item1_quantity)."\n";

   $email_message .= "price item1: ".clean_string($item1_subtotal)."\n";

   $email_message .= "item2: ".clean_string($item2_quantity)."\n";

   $email_message .= "price item2: ".clean_string($item2_subtotal)."\n";

   $email_message .= " item3: ".clean_string($item3_quantity)."\n";

   $email_message .= "price item3 ".clean_string($item3_subtotal)."\n";

   $email_message .= " item4 ".clean_string($item4_quantity)."\n";

   $email_message .= "Price item4: ".clean_string($item4_subtotal)."\n";

   $email_message .= "total price: ".clean_string($finaltotal)."\n";



$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".

'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .

'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  

?>





<?php

}

?>
```

Comment: Te recomiendo hacer el calculo en el lado del servidor, debido a que pueden capturar el metodo GET/POST y cambiar los valores

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Parece que tienes varias cosillas mal en tu código. Aquí te explico mis sugerencias para que puedas entender el porque de la solución:

1) Para enviar un dato al servidor desde el cliente hay varias formas:

1.- Usando **$.ajax**, documentación: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/
         Esta forma te ayudara a que no tengas que recargas la pagina ya que se manda en segundo plano una llamada al back (PHP) y cuando responde lo procesas en el cliente y puedes mostrar algún mensaje o procesar la respuesta.

2.- De la forma tradicional con un formulario e inputs, esto va a mandar al cliente a travez del navegador. Pero los elementos que pueden mandar datos al back solo son: **input, select, textarea, radio y checkbox**. En tu caso si tienes un:

```
<td class="label-success" id="finaltotal" name="finaltotal"></td>
```

Este va a fallar, por que el "td" no es un elemento que pueda mandar información.

2) Estas utilizando javascript puro, para hacer eso mismo que quieres hacer, te puedo sugerir que utilices **jQuery**, a menos que por alguna razón no puedas utilizarlo. También hay varias librerías de javascript que puedes utilizar como underscore. En la solución que te doy utilice bootstrap para dar un poco de estilo, puedes mantenerlo o quitarlo, solo utilice el css.

Ligas:
jquery docs: jquery.com
underscorejs docs: underscorejs.org
bootstrap docs: getbootstrap.com

---

Solución completa de lado del cliente:

Utilizando jQuery, $.ajax:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html> 
  <html>
   <head>
    <title>Send data to back</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h2>Send data to back example:</h2>
        <hr>
        <form id="valuesForm">
        <table class="table table-bordered">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Producto</th>
                    <th>Precio Unidad</th>
                    <th>Selección</th>
                    <th>Subtotal</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        item1
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        $<span id="unit-price-item-1">1</span>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <select class="selectQuantity" id="quantity-item-1" data-item-id="1" size="1">
                            <option value="10">10</option>
                            <option value="9">9</option>
                            <option value="8">8</option>
                            <option value="7">7</option>
                            <option value="6">6</option>
                            <option value="5">5</option>
                            <option value="4">4</option>
                            <option value="3">3</option>
                            <option value="2">2</option>
                            <option value="1">1</option>
                            <option value="0" selected>0</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td id="subtotal-price-item-1">
                        0
                    </td>
                </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    item2
                </td>
                <td>
                    $<span id="unit-price-item-2">2</span>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <select class="selectQuantity" id="quantity-item-2" data-item-id="2" size="1">
                        <option value="10">10</option>
                        <option value="9">9</option>
                        <option value="8">8</option>
                        <option value="7">7</option>
                        <option value="6">6</option>
                        <option value="5">5</option>
                        <option value="4">4</option>
                        <option value="3">3</option>
                        <option value="2">2</option>
                        <option value="1">1</option>
                        <option value="0" selected>0</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td id="subtotal-price-item-2">
                    0
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    item3
                </td>
                <td>
                    $<span id="unit-price-item-3">3</span>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <select class="selectQuantity" id="quantity-item-3" data-item-id="3" size="1">
                        <option value="10">10</option>
                        <option value="9">9</option>
                        <option value="8">8</option>
                        <option value="7">7</option>
                        <option value="6">6</option>
                        <option value="5">5</option>
                        <option value="4">4</option>
                        <option value="3">3</option>
                        <option value="2">2</option>
                        <option value="1">1</option>
                        <option value="0" selected>0</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td id="subtotal-price-item-3">
                    0
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    item4
                </td>
                <td>
                    $<span id="unit-price-item-4">4</span>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <select class="selectQuantity" id="quantity-item-4" data-item-id="4" size="1">
                        <option value="10">10</option>
                        <option value="9">9</option>
                        <option value="8">8</option>
                        <option value="7">7</option>
                        <option value="6">6</option>
                        <option value="5">5</option>
                        <option value="4">4</option>
                        <option value="3">3</option>
                        <option value="2">2</option>
                        <option value="1">1</option>
                        <option value="0" selected>0</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td id="subtotal-price-item-4">
                    0
                </td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
            <tfoot>
                <tr id="tablefoot">
                    <th class="button-ps">Total:</th>
                    <th colspan="2" class="button-ps" id="totalerr"></th>
                    <th class="label-success" id="finaltotal">0</th>
                </tr>
            </tfoot>
        </table>
        <input type="email" id="user-email" class="form-control" placeholder="your.email@server.com" required/>
        </br>
        <button id="send-mail" class="btn btn-success"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i> Send</button>
        </form>
    </div>            
</body>
<!-- JS Files at the bottom of the file -->
<!-- import jQuery  -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- import underscore  -->
<script src="http://underscorejs.org/underscore-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
    /* global $, _ */

    $('body').ready(function () {
        // Hago el hoiting de mis variables "globales" que voy a compartir a traves de todas las funciones para mandarlas al $.ajax
        var quantities = [],
            itemCounter,
            totalCharge = 0;

        /* 
        Este .each nos sirve para iterar todos los select con la clase "selectQuantity", y crear el objeto base con las cuentas, un id al select en el que estamos eso nos ayudara a saber a que select pertenece cada cuenta tambien lo utilizaremos para actualizar la cantidad seleccionada y el guardar la cantidad subtotal
        */
        $('.selectQuantity').each(function () {
            /*
            Con el each el this va a apuntar a cada select que estemos iterando, puedes hacer $(this).val() y te va a arrojar el valor del select en donde este el iterador.

            .push asi agregamos el objeto para cada select en el array de cantidades.
            */
            quantities.push({
                idItem: $(this).attr('id'),
                quantity: $(this).val(),
                subTotal: 0
            });
        });

        /*
            Este .on nos va a server para cachar el evento submit, cuando haces click en un boton del tipo "submit" y quiere enviar el formulario, lo hago de esta forma por si tienes un required en un input o algun tipo especial de HTML5, como type="email", se haga la validacion antes de enviar los datos. De igual forma es buena practica hacer una validacion en el back antes de hacer cualquier cosa.
        */
        $('#valuesForm').on('submit', function () {
            // obtenemos el email del usuario que introdujo en el input con id "user-email"
            var userEmail = $('#user-email').val();

            // Este es el $.ajax
            $.ajax({
                method: 'POST',
                url: 'myPage.php',
                data: {
                    values: quantities, // Aqui tu le pasas el nombre del post y el valor. Es decir lo vas a obtener
                    total: totalCharge, //  en PHP como $_POST['values'] , $_POST['total'] y $_POST['email'].
                    email: userEmail    // recuerda que "quantites" es un array de objetos tendras que hacer un foreach de $_POST['values'] si quieres sacar la cantidad seleccionada por cada item.
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data); // Este callback que se lanzara si la url 'myPage.php' responde como un status 200: OK, y lo que imprimas en php lo cachara el data.
                },
                error: function (data) {
                    console.log(data); // Este callback que se lanzara si la url 'myPage.php' responde con status de error, e.g. 400, 404, 500, etc...
                }
            });

            return false; // Este return es para que no se lanze el evento submit al navegador y no brinque de pagina, si no que se queda esperando la respuesta de nuestra llamada ajax.
        });

        /*
         En este on change vamos a cachar cada que cambian el select y podras hacer las cuentas de subtotal, también 
        saco el subtotal y lo ponga en su elemento.             
        */
        $('.selectQuantity').on('change', function () {
            //obtenemos el item "id", para usarlo mas adelante. También saco el precio unitario de cada item. 
            var itemId = $(this).attr('data-item-id'),
                unitPrice = $('#unit-price-item-' + itemId).text(),
                subTotal;

            // utilizo underscore _.findWhere para obtener el objeto del array que creamos hasta arriba de quantities. Puedes ver la documentacion en la pagina de underscore.
            itemCounter = _.findWhere(quantities, {idItem: $(this).attr('id')});
            // ahora como me regresa la referencia al objeto solo le cambio la cantidad de items, con eso se modifica el objeto de nuestro array quantities
            itemCounter.quantity = $(this).val();
            // obtengo el subtotal multiplicando la cantidad por el precio unitario
            subTotal = itemCounter.quantity * unitPrice;
            // guardo el subtotal en nuestro objeto.
            itemCounter.subTotal = subTotal;

            // imprimo el subtotal en el elemeneto de subtotal para ese item
            $('#subtotal-price-item-' + itemId).text(subTotal);
            //llamo esta funcion para imprimir el costo total de las selecciones.
            getTotalPrice();
        });

        // Esta funcion obtiene el precio total de toda la seleccion, la guarda en la variable totalCharge y la imprime en el elemento para el valor total.
        function getTotalPrice() {
            var totalPrice = 0;

            // recorremos todos los selects para obtener el precio de cada uno e irlo sumando.
            $('.selectQuantity').each(function () {
                var itemId = $(this).attr('data-item-id'),
                    unitPrice = $('#unit-price-item-' + itemId).text(),
                    quantity = $(this).val();

                totalPrice += unitPrice * quantity;
            });

            // guardo en nuestro variable "global" para mandarla por el $.ajax al server e imprimo el valor
            totalCharge = totalPrice;
            $('#finaltotal').text(totalPrice);
        }
    });
</script>
```

Con todo esto ya tienes tu tablita funcionando de lado de cliente y mandas a una pagina 'myPage.php'.

Puedes cachar los valores con $_POST,

$_POST['email'] => El email del usuario que introdujo en el texto.
$_POST['total'] => El total de la selección de los items.
$_POST['values'] => Aquí recibiras el objeto con todos los parametros que creamos, vas a necesitar un foreach:

```
 foreach ($_POST['values'] as $key => $value) {
   $value : {idItem: 'El id del item', quantity: 'La cantidad de items seleccionados', subTotal: 'El costo subtotal del precio unitario * la cantidad de items.'}
}
```

Y creo que con eso tienes lo que quieres hacer, si tienes alguna duda tu dime y lo revisamos!

Saludos

Comment: Muchisimas gracias por  tu tiempo iNavac. LLevo horas intentando hacer funcionar tu código pero no lo consigo. Realmente estoy atascado. El formulario me funciona bien cuando lo pruebo off-line pero a la hora de subirlo al servidor deja de funcionar. Las operaciones no se realizan. Ahora tampoco recibo cantidades en email de confirmación por lo que debo estar haciendo algo realmente mal en el php.

Comment: El codigo del front debería funcionar bien en local y server ya que se ejecuta de lado del cliente, posiblemente este mal del lado del server. Lo que puedes hacer es un die(var_dump($_POST)); y eso te va a arrojar todo lo que recibes como POST,  si eso esta vacío entonces el problema esta al enviar los datos. También asegúrate que la llamada $.ajax, tenga la ruta correcta en el parámetro "url" o el nombre correcto. Si tienes otra duda me dices ;)

Comment: Hola de nuevo iNavac. Tu codigo ha sido de gran ayuda. Muchisimas gracias. He estado trabajando con el en mis ratos libres  y creo que lo tengo casi funcionando. Lo unico que no consigo enviar por mail son los valores del foreach. He intentado con varias combinaciones pero no consigo que la información llegue al correo.  Me podrias echar una mano  con el php para el POST por favor. Gracias de nuevo.

Comment: Hola que tal! puedes revisar en el devtools de chrome, botón derecho > Inspeccionar elemento, y recargas, cuando recargue checa la tab de "Network" hay te dirá todo lo que has enviado por ajax. Aquí el link a la documentación: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools  Y con eso podrás ver que has enviado por ajax. Así podrás ver que le mandas y como lo puedes recibir en el $_POST. Si tienes mas dudas me dices. Saludos!

Comment: Muy buenas días! De verdad que te estoy muy agradecido por toda la ayuda que me estas dando. He revisado el envio de la información con developer chrome y se esta haciendo correctamente. Lo que no consigo descifrar es como llamar a esta informaci'on desde mi php. Por ejemplo para el itemem 1 esto es como developer me lo muestra tras hacer un pedido de 9 : values[0][idItem]:quantity_item_1
values[0][quantity]:9
values[0][subTotal]:9                         He intentado llamar a esta informacion desde mi php pero no consigo que me aparezca.

Comment: También he intentado usar el codigo URL encoded el cual es:  values%5B0%5D%5BidItem%5D
values%5B0%5D%5Bquantity%5D
values%5B0%5D%5BsubTotal%5D                     pero tampoco me sale nada. Te estaría eternamente agradecido si me pudieras poner un ejemplo para la llamada del dato [idItem] y values[0][quantity]. Muchas gracias de antemano iNavac.

Comment: Hola que tal, Mira si haces eso ultimo de mandarlo en la url, entonces lo tendrías que agarrar con $_GET porque va en la url, en el primer ejemplo que me pusiste de: values[0][idItem]:quantity_item_1, esto lo puedes iterar así:

 `foreach ($_POST['values'] as $value) {
   $value['idItem']; //el id item
   $value['quantity']; //la cantidad
}`

Comment: No tengo palabras para expresar todo mi agradecimiento. Muchísimas gracias. Sin ti hubiera sido imposible. Espero algún día ser de tanta ayuda con otros como tu lo has sido conmigo. Mil gracias de verdad.

Answer (score 0):

Buenas rlvysalm.

Corrige tu html , el atributo name solo puede ser asignado a elementos de formulario como inputs , textarea ... pero nunca a td.

```
<td class="label-success" id="finaltotal" name="finaltotal"></td>
```

Cambia por esto

```
<td>
  <input type="text" id="finaltotal" name="finaltotal" readonly placeholder="Total" />
</td>
```

Añade el tipo de metodo usado por el formulario

```
<form   id="contact-form" action="php/order.php"  method="post" >
```

Puedes darle css adicional para que no parezca un input.

Tras hacer esto, ya se enviará correctamente la variable finaltotal para que php la pueda tratar.

**ACTUALIZACION**

Cuando cambias

```
<td class="label-success" id="finaltotal" name="finaltotal"></td>
```

por esto

```
<td>
 <input type="text" id="finaltotal" name="finaltotal" readonly placeholder="Total" />
</td>
```

Tu javascript dejará de funcionar en esta linea

```
output.innerHTML = total.toFixed(4);
```

Esto es porque el elemento ahora no es un nodo que pueda tener nodos hijos. Ahora es un campo de texto y la propiedad para setearlo debe ser otra, exactamente value.

```
output = document.getElementById("finaltotal");
output.value = total.toFixed(4);
```

Una vez hecho esto ,tanto para la variable **finaltotal** como las que te hagan falta de igualar,  ya podrás enviar esos datos a través del formulario original o con ajax como te explicó @iNavac

Comment: Buenos días Angel, al introducir comando <input type="text" > la formula de mi javascript deja de funcionar :-(

Comment: Quizás debería añadir esto en mi JS? No tengo ni idea de como :-)

Comment: Perdona no te puse el código adaptado de javascript .

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que usar ajax, te dejo un ejemplo sencillo, con codigo comentado.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>login</title>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

        $(window).on('load', function() {           

            var datoAenviar = 'idUsuario';

            $('#botonEnviar').click(function(event) {               

                event.preventDefault();

                var request = $.ajax({
                    method : 'POST',
                    url    : 'login.php',//el archivo server .php al que quieres enviar                    
                    data   : {
                        dato : datoAenviar//dato que quieres enviar
                    },
                    dataType    : 'json' //el tipo de dato tambien puede ser text
                });

                request.done(function(response) { 
                    if(response.status) {
                        alert('Success: ' + response.result + "\n Message: " + response.message);
                        window.location.href = 'login.php';
                    }
                    else {
                        alert('Error: ' + response.message);
                        window.location.href = window.location.href;
                    }
                });

                request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
                    alert("Server request failed: " + textStatus);
                    window.location.href = '';
                });
            });

        });


        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="formulario">
            <p><input type="text "id="clickme"  placeholder="n o m b r e"></p>
            <p><input type="text "id="pass"  placeholder=" c o n t r a s e n a"></p>
            <input type="button" id="botonEnviar" value="enviar">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

y el server login.php: tiene que recibir la variable dato

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST) && isset($_POST['dato'])){//recuperas el dato
    header('Content-Type: application/json');

    $resultado = $_POST['dato'];

    echo json_encode(array(//pruebas si funciona imprimiendolo
        'status' => 1,
        'result' => $resultado,
        'message' => "Todo bien"
    ), true);
}
```

Comment: Muy buenas, he intentado seguir to consejo pero no me ha dado resultado. Debo de estar haciendo algo mal. A mi PHP le he añadido: 
    header('Content-Type: application/json');  

    $finaltotal = $_POST['finaltotal'];                                                                  Ya mi html le he añadido todo lo que me has puesto   cambiando el dato a enviar por finaltotal y el nombre del php pero nada. solo me siguen llegando las cantidades.  Se debe cambiar tambíen: var datoAenviar = 'idUsuario';  ?? Muchas gracias

Comment: @rlvysalm puedes modificar tu pregunta con los cambios que realizaste porfavor, y si debes cambiar el valor de la variable `datoAenviar`